# I'm not able to find configurations like QA, QA-Hot, Stage, Stage-Hot, Ad-Hoc and Appstore in MAUI

Tags: maui, configurationmanager, adhoc

I'm checking  the **configuration manager** of my **migrated .NET MAUI Android app** which is migrated from Xamarin. I can find some of the **configurations missing**. These are the **configurations** of my **Migrated .NET MAUI app**:

[image]

and in **.NET MAUI** these are the configurations:

[image]

but in **Xamarin** these are the configurations:

[image]

I need to know why **QA, QA-Hot, Stage, Stage-Hot, Ad-Hoc and Appstore configurations** are not present in .NET MAUI?

Comment: Configurations are defined in the solution file

Comment: @Jason So how we can define QA, QA-Hot, Stage, Stage-Hot, Ad-Hoc and Appstore configurations in solution file of .net MAUI?

Comment: Create them using the “new” function in the dropdown

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the solution. It will be good if you can provide me a documentation which can help me to create configuration. I checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2022 but it was not helpful.

Comment: What more documentation do you need?  Or I imagine you can copy the old configs from the Xamarin solution to the MAUI solution.